# C# - How to use unassigned variable in try catch block

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

`crmFactory.RegisterDemoAccount` throws `Exception`.  In order to use the variable `res` I need to initialize it.

Since `AccountRegistrationResponse` is not initializable, how can I declare `res` without getting compilation errors about using unassigned variables?
I can assign it to null, but I don't think this is a good programming approach.

```
AccountRegistrationResponse res /*=null*/; 
 try
 {
  res = crmFactory.RegisterDemoAccount(CrmConfigRepository.CrmOwnerUserId
                                   , CrmConfigRepository.CrmOrganizationName
                                   , CrmConfigRepository.CrmBusinessUnitName
                                   , demo.getData());
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
      _log.Error("Cannot create demo account", e);
 }
 _log.Debug(res.getString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your reluctance to assign `res` to null - it feels pointless, and therefore wrong. It is a common approach in situations like this, though, when an object is needed outside the block in which it's assigned. Assuming you're doing the right thing in assigning your variable in a try/catch block (and it's not an uncommon pattern, in many cases), I wouldn't worry about it.

However, what would happen if the assignment failed? The second logging call would try to dereference `res`, and throw a `NullReferenceException`. That's not good.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to continue your method after catching an unknown exception. Anything could have gone wrong and it makes no sense to assume that it's safe to continue. Only bad things can happen if you try.

Either return an error result, or better, just rethrow the original exception:

```
 catch (Exception e)
 {
      _log.Error("Cannot create demo account", e);
      throw;
 }
```

Now the compiler can see that `res` will always be assigned after the try block completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the logging line inside the try/catch so that the compiler knows that `res` has been initialised.

```
try
{
    res = ...
    _log.Debug(res.getString()); }
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.Error("Cannot create demo account", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's THE right approach. Only thing, if `null` is a valid return value of `RegisterDemoAccount`, you could add a `bool initialized = false` that you set to `true` just after the `RegisterDemoAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to null, like you said, if you need it outside of try/catch. It's not bad way of programming.

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't think this is a good programming approach.

Why? If you don't initialise `res` and then `RegisterDemoAccount(...)` (or another expression before it) throws then `res` will not be assigned in the `try` statement.

Therefore execution could reach the final statement (after the `catch` block) with `res` unassigned.

The problem is the use of `res` in that last statement – the compiler can see it can get to this point without initialisation.